# Problem with Openpay.framework 2.0.2 when uploading the build to the appstore

Tags: ios, code-signing

I have compiled my application but when I try to upload it to Appstore Connect I get an error when signing the Openyay.framework.

[image]

Comment: Please add distribution logs.

Comment: Here is the file of the distribution logs: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wn83SLEYa9Ooqgof_cXXN8FBKybdJEDL